# how to filter a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, filter

I have a gridview connected to a database by sqldatasource. I have multiple drop down lists and a table where users can select different data to filter the gridview.

I know how to set this up for one control but have no idea how to do it for multiple ones. Ideally what I would like to do is `onfilterButton_Click` the code behind connects to a stored procedure in the database. The parameters would depend on the filter options the user has chosen. I just don't know how to write the stored procedure. (I am not the best at SQL)

But I am open to suggestions of better ways to do this. I am using c# visual studios 2010 and sql server 2008.

I have been stuck on this for over a week now so really any practical help would be welcome.

Comment: In DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged Event, Pass the DropDownlist value as InPut Parameter to your Sp and filter and displayed it in the Grid

Comment: @thevan Do you have any example of how to do this? I know in theory that this what I want but I have not been able to make it happen.

Comment: i have added one answer, i think this is what u want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not good in writing `SP's` then you can directly filter your SQL `DataSource` by using the `FilterExpression` property.

```
sql.FilterExpression = "Filteration Expression";
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Edit:** Something that will work for you:

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text != "All")
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Title like '" + textbox1.Text + "' and Category like " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    }
    else
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "Title like '" + textbox1.Text + "'";
    }

 GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: that you for replying. I have looked into using a FilterExpression but can only find examples of how it is used for one textbox or one dropdownlist. How do I use it for multiple ones?

Comment: Check this article for multiple ones http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/web/ui/webcontrols/SqlDataSourceClassFilterExpression.aspx

Comment: filterexpression = "title LIKE '%{0}%' or url LIKE '%{0}%'"> I presume I can change the 'or' to 'and' to make it filter for both at the same time. But is it possible to only filter for title or url if the selected value is not 'All' for example?

Comment: I will try tonight to see which answer I can get to work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Write One Stored Procedure and Pass DropDownList values as Parameters like this:

```
 CREATE PROC CUST_Details
 (
 @CustomerID INT,
 @CompanyID INT
 )
 AS
 BEGIN

    SELECT
               Customer.CustomerName,
               Company.CompanyName
    FROM
       Customer INNER JOIN
       Company ON Customer.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID
        WHERE
       (@CompanyID = -1 OR Customer.CompanyID = @CompanyID) AND
       (@CustomerID = -1 OR Customer.CustomerID = @CustomerID)

 END
```

Before that, in your DropDownList add item such as "<-----Select----->" as DataTextField and "-1" as DataValueField.

In Both DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged Event, pass DropDownList's SelectedValue as parameters and once again call the database and databind it with the Grid.

Comment: I will try tonight to see which answer I can get to work. I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure would declare all your parameters like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
 @parameter1 varchar(50),
 @parameter2 int    
etc...
```

Then you would call your stored procedure with the parameters like:

```
GetData(dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Value, dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Is that the sort of thing you mean?

UPDATE:
For a situation where the 'All' option was chosen, you could still pass the value as a null parameter, and in the stored procedure you would declare it as 'optional':

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
     @parameter1 varchar(50) = NULL,
     @parameter2 int
```

So the query in your stored procedure would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE  ((@parameter1 IS NULL) OR (column1 = @parameter1 )) 
AND column2 = @parameter2
```

Comment: yes that is basically what I want. this maybe a stupid question but how do I do it when for the ddl the options are 'All', 'Yes' and 'No. So I only want it to filter from that selected DDL if the selected value is 'Yes' or 'No'.

Comment: I will try tonight to see which answer I can get to work. Thanks for your help

Comment: I would advise against selecting ALL columns but instead select the columns you need to work with. This reduces data processing, traffic and also security issues (such as selecting all columns means any sensitive information will also be selected)

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas - While I agree with your comment, if you read my query example properly you'll see it's essentially psuedo-code. Hardly worth reviving a 2.5yr old answer for, but thanks for your input.

Comment: @markpsmith - did not realise it was quite old :) it was on the home page on my account.... and to me, doesn't matter that much about how old it is, as long as its not decades old ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below might give you idea how this works, please check:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="FORM1" runat="server">

            <p>Show all employees with the following title:
            <asp:DropDownList
                id="DropDownList1"
                runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Sales Representative</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Sales Manager</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Vice President, Sales</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></p>

            <asp:SqlDataSource
                id="SqlDataSource1"
                runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnection %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Title FROM Employees"
                FilterExpression="Title='{0}'" OnFiltering="SqlDataSource1_Filtering">
                <FilterParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Title" ControlId="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
                </FilterParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource><br />

            <asp:GridView
                id="GridView1"
                runat="server"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <columns>
                    <asp:BoundField Visible="False" DataField="EmployeeID" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="FirstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="LastName" />
                </columns>
            </asp:GridView>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server Side:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Filtering(object sender, SqlDataSourceFilteringEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = e.ParameterValues[0].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I understand how it works for one filter parameter but didnt know how to do it for many. But the other answers have given me a few ways to do it. Hopefully I will have it solved when I get home from work.